# Oracle SQL find minumum value above a certain threshold

Tags: sql, oracle

Had a quick google to see if this can be done without much luck, but is there any way in oracle sql to return the minumum value of something but above a certain number (i.e. minimum value above negative numbers).  Currently I'm using this line of code

```
 min(ROUND(IA.ASM_START_DATE -REF.ASM_START_DATE,0)) over (partition by  IA.ASM_ID) min_wk
```

To return the lowest difference grouped by ID - it's working to a point, but I want it to bring back the lowest difference above -10. Ideally I'm trying to achieve this in the select rather than using the where query, as I want to use it to identify issues but not exclude them from the report completely.

Comment: didn't try this, but off top of my head, maybe using having with a min > -10?

Comment: It would be more useful if you posted a complete SQL statement.  Also, what do you mean by "I'm trying to achieve this in the select rather than using the where query, as I want to use it to identify issues but not exclude them from the report completely."  Do you want the output to contain values less than -10 or not?  If not, it seems logical to me, to exclude them in the WHERE clause.  Best you can do in the SELECT list is to "re-map" them to different values, as ABS did below.  But it's not clear to me why you'd do it that way.

Comment: The query is quite large, so I didn't really want to post it all as I didn't think it would make it any clearer.  It's quite hard to explain succinctly, and I think there's definitely a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do but I thought it might be helpful to at least get it working and then possibly post it to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve (and improve upon)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple hack is to use a case statement to set any values that are too low to null so they won't change the minimum:

```
min(case when ROUND(IA.ASM_START_DATE -REF.ASM_START_DATE,0)<-10 then null else ROUND(IA.ASM_START_DATE -REF.ASM_START_DATE,0) end) over (partition by  IA.ASM_ID)
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.  I did think about this but wasn't sure about using case with min (I was thinking of putting the min within the case then thought it wouldn't work).  Will try this tomorrow, many thanks.